# One Way Replication of Oracle 11g to MSSQL 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, oracle, replication, synchronization, ssrs

We're in the midst of a major LOB system change which will use Oracle 11g, but we need to maintain a LARGE number of existing reports in SSRS.

What is a good method to automate a one-way, read-only synchronization/replication/dump of a 400GB Oracle 11g database to MSSQL 2008R2 while minimizing the data moved?  The 400GB data will be a ETL/subset snapshot of a larger database, so no direct backup/restore, and I believe the data will be flushed between snapshots and not be an incremental update.

Due to the sensitivity of the data, and the relationship of the business units, I think the best we're going to be able to do is get either an ETL to a separate Oracle DB or possibly views, then we need to take it from there.

The servers will be in the same data center, so assume low-latency high bandwidth access.

Comment: probably belongs on DBA.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Oracle DB as a replication publisher, and set up transactional replication to the MSSQL DB (the *subscriber*):

[How to: Create a Publication from an Oracle Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152481.aspx)